# Mostrar banner fixo no rodapé do site

Tags: javascript, html, css

Gostaria de mostrar um banner fixo na rodapé do meu site, porem quero que ele acompanhe o conteúdo do site conforma for rolando o site para baixou ou para cima, já consegui mostrar o banner, más não consegui fazer com que ele acompanhasse a pagina.

Meu código:

```
<div id='barra' style='position:relative; min-height: 100%; left:-02px; width:100%;'>

<iframe border='0' class='overlay2' frameborder='0' height='55' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' scrolling='No' src='http://Publicidades.html' style='max-width: 630%; width: 100%;'/></div>
```

Tentei utilizar esse CSS mais não deu certo.

```
<style>

    /*Esconde a dive de classe Overlay caso seja identificado que o width Mobile maximo deseja igual ou menor que 980px*/
    @media only screen and (min-width: 980px){
        .overlay2 { display: none; }

    #barra { bottom: 0; display: block; height: 50px; position: relative; width: 100%; background: #000; }

</style>
```

Por favor alguém me ajuda!!

Comment: Você quer que o rodapé fique sempre visível na parte de baixo do ecrã? Experimenta trocar o `position: relative;` pelo `position: fixed;`, algo do tipo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/Lsn3t772/

Answer (score 1):

Olá, coloque o elemento com posição fixa!

```
#barra { bottom: 0; left: 0; display: flex; justify-content: center; height: 50px; position: fixed; width: 100%; background: #000; }
```

Caso surja alguma dúvida, deixe ai!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Fiz exatamente o que vocês me indicaram, deu certo!!